# NGINX doesn't work if the domain has an accent mark

Tags: http, nginx, server

I have bought a domain with an accent mark inside: something like www.èxample.com.

My problem is that even if I configured my nginx server block (virtual host) in a correct way, it doesn't match the directory that I made.
I tried to use the same configuration with a domain without an accent mark and everything work fine.

This is my server block file inside site-availables folder:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/example.com;
    index index.php index.html index.html;

    server_name *.èxample.com;

    client_max_body_size 4G;

    charset utf-8;

    access_log /var/www/example.com/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /var/www/example.com/logs/nginx-error.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on the php-fpm socket
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: You should use punycode. Try `*.xn--xample-2ua.com`

Comment: https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,44682,44795#msg-44795

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyTen but unfortunately it still doesn't work. My domain points to the server but it shows me the "Welcome to nginx!" page.

Comment: Do you have link to your config in `sites-enabled` folder?

Comment: Yes, I tried the same configuration using a domain without accent mark and everything works fine.